# Dynamicly add items to NavigationDrawer menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a basic question and I'm surprised I didn't find a topic that already treats that matter: I have trouble adding elements to my navigation drawer menu.

I kept a reference of the menu  :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_pager, menu);
        mMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }
```

And in the callback of an AsyncTask, I try to add items to my menu this way :

```
mMenu.add("title").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_group);
```

Idealy I'd like to add it in the "menu_group" group, but for now I try it that way.

> layout/activity_main_pager

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_pager"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_pager_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> menu/activity_main_pager_drawer

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="@string/menu_title_groups">
        <menu>
            <group android:id="@+id/menu_groups">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_add_group"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_group_add"
                    android:title="@string/menu_add_group" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Bonus question : The icon of "menu_add_group" item of my menu doesn't display correctly, I have a gray square instead of it.

Thanks, don't hesitate to link me an other topic if I didn't search correclty.

---

Ok one of the problems was the way I got my mMenu. I added all the corrections listed by my savior plus this one :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_pager, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

and on my activity init :

```
NavigationView nav = (NavigationView) mDrawer.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
mMenu = nav.getMenu();
```

when I add a menu item :

```
menu.add("title").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_group);
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the menu items you need to call [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) (or [supportInvalidateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) if you're using the support library). Android will then know that it needs to recreate it and will call `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` again. You'll need to inflate the new menu there.

The grey icon is due to the item tint. You can remove it by simply calling `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null)`.

Comment: Still does not print my menus items. I must have more than one flaw in my code.

The setItemIconTintList(null) does its job thought ! thanks !

Comment: You still need to inflate your menu properly in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)`. I've updated my answer to explicitly mention it.

Comment: I have the feeling I shouldn't get my menu in the onCreateOptionMenu, is there an other way ?

Comment: Ok that was the way I got the menu. Solve that by gettting it from navigation view. I update my question and thank you very much !